# Ajax polling stops to poll after internet disconnect

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, hibernate, sleep

I have a sort of ajax polling cycle - pull message, process message, wait, pull again ... - everything works fine until user disconnects from the internet (it can be even so simple user action as sleep/hibernating the PC). After that - at least in latest Chrome - POST fails (logicly) - but after reconnecting to the internet the poll cycle does not get started again (even when the session is still ON).

```
jQuery(function(){
// ba polling main
    function pollingMain() {
          $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: ba_home_url+"/pollingscript.php",
              data: { 
                "load": "something",
                "data-one": 0,
                "data-two": 0
              },
              dataType: "json",
              timeout: 60000, 
              success: function(data) {
                  if( data.status == 'nodata' ){ 
                    setTimeout(pollingMain,10000);
                  } else{ 
                    if( data.status == 'okdata' ){
                      console.log('Ok data recived');
                      setTimeout(pollingMain,10000); 
                    } else{
                      //server responded with something we dont know what is
                      setTimeout(pollingMain,10000); 
                    }
                  }

              },
              error: function(request, status, err) {
                  if(status == "timeout") {
                      setTimeout(pollingMain,10000);
                  }
              }
          });
    }
    pollingMain();

});
```

That is my code. I guess I am missing something in the error callback - but what error status handling should I add there ?

Comment: `ba_home_url` = ? Is it `localhost`, `IP Address`, `Computer Name`

Comment: Just an url_base - that is not the problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking for specific status "timeout". Add else statement for handling other statuses.